# Ошибка в коде проверки кошельков

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, requests

```
try:
    f = open('bitco.txt', 'r')
    line = f.readlines()
    address = line
    ret = requests.post('https://api.blockchair.com/{:btc_chain}/addresses/balances')
    t = ret.text
    print(t)
finally:
    brawser.close()
    brawser.quit()
```

Никак не могу проверить свои 32 кошелька на баланс.
Пробовал `blockcypher` и `requests`,`selenium`...
Что я делаю не так?
выдает такое-

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Page Not Found</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 36px;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">
                    Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Page Not Found</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 36px;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">
                    Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.                </div>
```

Хотелось что то типа такого зделать:

```
19MS4h6P7VvSsE2uKbNEHpGqQkcyde9Ra5 - bal:0.00201600 BTC
```

Один проверяетца, а много нет.Знаю код корявый и не очень но я только учусь пользоватца данной библиотекой.Файл с таким типом строк :19MS4h6P7VvSsE2uKbNEHpGqQkcyde9Ra5 .
Ответ; я уже нашол вот в этой теме вопрос.(пс код лутше моего)
https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2418360.html

Comment: добавьте в вопрос минимальный воспроизводимый пример, ошибку и ожидаемое поведение...

Comment: Странно строка выглядит `'https://api.blockchair.com/{:btc_chain}/addresses/balances'` там вместо `{:btc_chain}` не должно что-то подставляться?

Comment: Не знаю впервые работаю с api читал документацию так написано понял что это строка.Вот посмотрите сами https://blockchair.com/api/docs#link_M04 , пробывал даже внизу пример с коментария но и у него выбевает ошибки хотя указывал еще и тайминг и прочее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно не усложнять и сделать все обычным запросом.
сделать цикл и прогнать.

```
wallet ='1BvBMSEYstWetqTFn5Au4m4GFg7xJaNVN2'
requests.get(f'https://chain.api.btc.com/v3/address/{wallet}')
```

Comment: Пасиб попробую:)

Comment: Не работает выдает штмл страницу без балланса .